# angular js function does not return value to be shown at autocomplete

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

here is my angular script that does an autocomplete:

```
angular.module( "myApp", ['ngAutocomplete']).controller("myController",function ($scope) {

                        $scope.result1 = '';
                        $scope.options1 = null;
                        $scope.details1 = '';


                        $scope.products = [];
                            $scope.addItem = function () {
                                $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
                            }


                  });



                    angular.module( "ngAutocomplete", []).directive('ngAutocomplete', function($parse) {

                        return {

                          scope: {
                            details: '=',
                            ngAutocomplete: '=',
                            options: '='
                          },

                          link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
                            var opts

                            var initOpts = function() {

                              opts = {}
                              if (scope.options) {
                                if (scope.options.types) {
                                  opts.types = []
                                  opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
                                }
                                if (scope.options.bounds) {
                                  opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
                                }
                                if (scope.options.country) {
                                  opts.componentRestrictions = {
                                    country: scope.options.country
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            initOpts()


                            var newAutocomplete = function() {
                              scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], opts);
                              google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                                scope.$apply(function() {

                                    scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();

                                  scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
                                });
                              })
                            }
                            newAutocomplete()



                          }
                        };
                      });
```

**The HTML tag that uses the js is:**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Airport Code or City Name" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="addMe">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem()">Add to Itinerary</button>

                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{result1}}</li>
                </ul>
```

this adds the newly called value to the <li>
Each value is added to <li>
But replaces the previous.

Meaning:

**WHAT HAPPENS:**

First I added: San Francisco --> list:

San Francisco

Second, I added Santa Clara --> list:

Santa Clara

Santa Clara

Third, I added Santa Monica --> list:

Santa Monica

Santa Monica

Santa Monica

**WHAT IS EXPECTED:**

First I added: San Francisco --> list:

San Francisco

Second, I added Santa Clara --> list:

Santa Clara

San Francisco

Third, I added Santa Monica --> list:

Santa Monica

Santa Clara

San Francisco

http://plnkr.co/edit/iyJ1cFVizjcWbh3PCYBJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing `{{result1}}` for all the `<li>` elements. Replace `{{result1}}` with `{{x}}` . Change the addItem() function also in your code. Replace `$scope.addMe` with `$scope.result1`. For the list to be shown in reverse order , you can use a custom filter.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Airport Code or City Name" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1" ng-model="addMe">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addItem()">Add to Itinerary</button>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in products | reverse">{{x}}</li> <!-- Replace result1 with x --> 
            </ul>


$scope.addItem = function () {
     $scope.products.push($scope.result1); // Replace $scope.addMe with $scope.result1
}

/* Custom Filter */
angular.module( "myApp").filter('reverse', function() {
   return function(items) {
     return items.slice().reverse();
   };
});
```

Comment: that does add an item to the &lt;li&gt; but it does not display any thing,... Meaning, I can see a bullet added, but no text that I enter in the text field

Comment: Nope :| it did not.